# Batch: Addition and subtraction on number read from input

Tags: math, batch-file, addition, subtraction

I've got a script file which takes a number between 1 and 5, then has to map that input to another number to give to a program. Very simple: if it's less than or equal to 2, subtract one. Higher, add one.

Here's the business part of my script:

```
set /p reason=Reason code:

if %reason%==q (
    goto eof
)
if %reason% GEQ 1 (
    if %reason% LEQ 5 (
        if %reason% LEQ 2 (
            set /a code=%reason%-1
        ) else (
            set /a code=%reason%+1
        )
    echo %code%
    )
)
```

I have this going in a loop with goto. First iteration, press 1. It says echo is off. Press 1 again, and it equals zero, as expected. Press 2, it says one. 2 again, it says 1, as expected.

I've confirmed that it consistently says what it should taking input from the last loop (or nothing if it's the first). Pressing 'q' to quit works every time.

Echoing in the right places, I confirm it's meeting the conditions just fine. It's also setting reason just fine. It doesn't seem to have a problem reading in numbers, as all the conditions work as expected (so if I press 5, then 6, it blocks the 6, rather than think I gave it 5).

I have another script with the same arithmetic operations, and that works fine. I can't see any difference between those lines other than the name of the variable (I was previously setting it back to the reason variable, but changed to code for clarity).

Comment: are you sure you have posted exactly the same code? are you sure the test case that is failing with "echo is OFF" is when trying "1"?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by your use of `%` variables. Those variables are expanded at parse time, i.e. when an instruction is read by the interpreter. Conditionals are read as one instruction, so `%code%` is being expanded when `if %reason% GEQ 1 (...)` is being read. At this point, the assignment in the innermost conditional has not yet been made, so `%code%` is still empty (until after the conditional has been processed). That's why you get `ECHO is off` after the first iteration, and a value each time thereafter (you're actually seeing the code from the last iteration there).

Enable delayed expansion and use `!` variable syntax for the `code` variable inside the conditional:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p "reason=Reason code: "

if "%reason%"=="q" goto :eof

if %reason% GEQ 1 (
  if %reason% LEQ 5 (
    if %reason% LEQ 2 (
      set /a "code=%reason%-1"
    ) else (
      set /a "code=%reason%+1"
    )
    echo !code!
  )
)
```

If you don't want `!code!` to become greater than 5 you need to fix your logic, though, e.g. like this:

```
if %reason% GEQ 1 (
  if %reason% LEQ 5 (
    if %reason% LEQ 2 (
      set /a "code=%reason%-1"
    ) else if %reason% EQU 5 (
      set "code=%reason%"
    ) else (
      set /a "code=%reason%+1"
    )
    echo !code!
  )
)
```

Also, you need `goto :eof`, not `goto eof`. Omitting the colon will give you a "missing label" error.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
set /p reason=Reason code:

if "%reason%"=="q" goto :eof

if %reason% LEQ 2 set /a reason-=1
if %reason% GTR 2 set /a reason+=1
```